# Sending HTTP requests via VB or VBA, increasing max size of post sendable

Tags: vba, vb6

I am writing with VB 6.0 (yes, that early version) and am using "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" to post data to a URL.

I noticed that data beyond the size 64K gets truncated.

Is there a way to increase that limit on the sender side. How can i do it in VBA/VB 6.0.

thank you,

Dan

p.s. I read that in php one can increase that size to tens of MB with a simple setting -- can this be done in VB as well.

Edit:

Here is some sample code:

I added "Contents-Length" after i posed the question, after noticing this on the web, related to multi-part messages,  but its unclear to me if this works. The server still echos' back a truncated "payload" in the result.

```
Dim objWinHttp As Variant
Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

Dim url As String
url = "https://destination.com/api/v1/destination1

objWinHttp.Open "post", url, False

objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(json)
objWinHttp.send json

Dim result As String
result = = objWinHttp.responseText
```

Comment: You will need to show the code you're using.

Comment: Looks like they do provide the option. See (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384086(v=vs.85).aspx) for details, but maybe it can only be done in a c++ environment? If I were you, upgrade the technology you are using.

Comment: the technology choice isn't mine -- its an existing code base that i need to add to. In the longer term, it can, perhaps, be migrated (or rewritten?) with a more modern technology (vb.net, perhaps)

Comment: Digging around in the link that Jeremy provided, I find this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx and this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383998(v=vs.85).aspx . They don't have VB6 examples, but you should be able to figure out what you need. Try this: `objWinHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_MaxResponseHeaderSize) = 256`, for example.

Comment: There are some typos in your code here (the line setting the url variable doesn't have a close-quote & the line setting result uses two equal signs). And, can you clarify how you're testing that the post body that's being sent is truncated? Are you sure it's not an issue with trying to read whatever "the server echos" back?

Comment: Thank you Peter.

I edited the URL to take out any customer specific information, and missed the quotes. 

Its a good point -- i am sending to a test server that belongs to a 3rd party. I am indeed trying to acertain what they actually received and, reading your comment, i need to check what they sent out back, as well. Thanks!

Comment: Use `curl` to make sure the *server* is not truncating this huge POST request (most probably).

Comment: How big is a recommended (or typical) post request.

I can probably suggest sending in junks.